Question about a possible application of Burnside's basis theorem
Let $G=\langle a_1,\dots , a_d\rangle$ be a $d$-generator $p$-group of order $p^n$ (i.e. $d$ is the minimal number of generators).
Further let $N$ be a characteristic and elementary abelian subgroup of $G$ such that $N\leq Z(G)$. If $\pi: G \to G/N$ is the canonical epimorphism and $(b_1,\dots,b_d)\in G^d$ such that $\pi(a_i) = \pi(b_i)$ for all $i$, why does it follow that $G=\langle b_1,\dots,b_d\rangle$? I suppose that one can use Burnside's basis theorem in a way, but I do not see how $N$ relates to the Frattini group.
What I have tried: Obviously, $G/N = \langle \pi(a_1),\dots,\pi(a_d)\rangle = \langle \pi(b_1),\dots,\pi(b_d)\rangle$. This yields $G = \langle N, b_1,\dots, b_d\rangle$. Nevertheless I cannot deduce $N\subseteq \langle b_1,\dots,b_n\rangle$.

This doesn't seem to be true even for abelian $p$-groups.
Let $G=\langle a_1,a_2\mid a_1^{p^2}=a_2^p=e,a_1a_2=a_2a_1\rangle$, $N=\langle a_1^p,a_2\rangle$, and $b_1=a_1$, $b_2=e$. It is easy to see that $N$ is a characteristic subgroup of the group $G$ and $\pi(a_1)=\pi(b_1), \pi(a_2)=\pi(b_2)$, however $G\neq\langle b_1,b_2\rangle$.  Or quite simply. Take $G$ to be an elementary abelian $p$-group and $N=G$.

Where is this question from? Perhaps there are more assumptions on $G$?

It is from https://arxiv.org/abs/1806.07462v1, Lemma 2.7 (in German) on p.10. From my understanding, the author uses that every $x \in X$ is a generating set of $G$, a fact which I cannot believe.

In the proof, one considers the set $$X = {(x_1,\dots,x_d)\in G^d\mid \pi(x_i) = \pi(a_i)\ \forall i}$$ and every element of $X$ is supposed to be a generating set of $G$. Am I missing another assumption here?

I can only read German when I have a computer in front of me :) I can translate this when I'm home later today and see if I can decipher what's going on.

@kabenyuk this is true, thanks! There must be something more implicitly assumed in the proof of the paper.

@SteveD Thank you for your help! Let me know if I can help you with translating!

After thinking some more about this, I think the author tried to mimick Burnside's proof that the kernel of the homomorphism $\mathrm{Aut}(G) \to \mathrm{Aut}(G/\Phi(G))$ is a $p$-group. See e.g. Gorenstein, Theorem 1.4 in Chapter 5. There one also uses a specific action on minimal generating sets.

I don't think I believe this lemma. If we take $G=D_8$ or $Q_8$ with $N=Z(G)$, then the subgroup of ${\rm Aut}(G)$ that induces the identity on $G/N$ has order $2^2$, but this lemma says it has order $2^{d(n-k)}=2^4$. If $N \le \Phi(G)$ then the order of the subgroup is $p^{dk}$ ratyher than $p^{d(n-k)}$, but this is not clear otherwise.

@DerekHolt yes, you are right, I double checked this in MAGMA.

Just for reference: I try to prove that the group (named T in the above theorem) from Lemma 3.3 of Eick's et al. "Constructing automorphism groups of p-groups" is an elementary abelian $p$-group and I stumbled across this "lemma" mentioned in my question...
